# How to convert an array of date strings to an array of date objects, Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

Looked at similar SO questions and found that there are no answers in Swift, there are plenty of answers exclusively for date formatting but not in combination with iteration.

I have an array of date strings like the below:

```
let dateStrings = ["2016-12-22T08:00:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:15:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:30:00-08:00"]
```

I would like to convert them to an array of local dateObjects like the below

```
var dateObjects = [2016-12-22 21:30:00 +0530, 2016-12-22 21:45:00 +0530, 2016-12-22 22:00:00 +0530]
```

I've tried iterating through the array of date strings but I get this error :

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

So I tried with optional binding without success. Please advice where I could be going wrong.

```
var dateObjects = [Date]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
for date in dateStrings{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    self.dateObjects.append(dateObject!)  // ERROR LINE
}
```

When I try with optional binding its going through else statement printing "Unable to convert to date object"

```
for date in dateStrings{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    if let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date){
        self.dateObjects.append(dateObject!)  // ERROR LINE
    }
    else{
        print("Unable to convert to date object")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey i ran you code, everything work just fine. not error. are you sure that is the line which cause the error??

Comment: Interesting, your code works for me...

Comment: you do not need to use `self.dateObjects.append(dateObject!)` use only `dateObjects.append(dateObject!)` it will work

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but why do you set the formatter's `dateFormat` inside the loop? Just set it once before the loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In second case you are force wrapping non-optional value there is no need of that and you are writing self with dateObjects `var` that is not declare as a instance property, also you can simply use `flatMap` to reduce your code and create array of `Date` from array of `String`.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
let dateObjects = dateStrings.flatMap { dateFormatter.date(from: $0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: date object is local variable so remove self. if you want use self then make it global

```
    let dateStrings = ["2016-12-22T08:00:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:15:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:30:00-08:00"]

    var dateObjects = [Date]()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"

    for date in dateStrings{
        let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
        dateObjects.append(dateObject!) 
    }

    print(dateObjects)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove self from `dateObjects`.

`dateObjects` is local variable. So don't use self with `dateObjects`.

```
var dateObjects = [Date]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
for date in dateStrings{
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
    let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
   dateObjects.append(dateObject!)  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did was that I mapped over the the array and made each item into a new `Date` object.

```
let dateObjects = _.map(dateStrings, (dateString) => new Date(dateString)
```

It's that easy. In my case, I was trying to compare the dates to another array of dates so after doing `new Date(dateString)` I converted them back into a ISOString by doing

```
let dateObjects = _.map(dateStrings, (dateString) => new Date(dateString).toISOString()
```

**Note:**
You don't need to use `_.map`, you could just use `.map`

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

**Swift 3**

```
let dateStrings = ["2016-12-22T08:00:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:15:00-08:00", "2016-12-22T08:30:00-08:00"]

func convertDate(str: String) -> Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"
        let dateObject = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
    return(dateObject!)
}

var stringDates : [Date] = []

for date in dateStrings {
    stringDates.append(convertDate(str: dateStrings[0]))
}
```

Comment: Good answers explain what the problem was and good answers explain how their answer solves the problem. Code-only answers are frowned upon here.